# How to convert an empty string to integer value 0

Tags: python-3.6

Good day. I am a newbie in creating a python program. My program is to write code that prints Hello if 1 is stored in spam, prints Howdy if 2 is stored in spam, and prints Greetings! if anything else is stored in spam.

My problem is that I would like to repeat the process if the user will not input anything or an empty value. How will I convert '' to value 0. Thanks. Im sorry if my program is not that good.

```
while True:
    print ('Enter value of spam')
    spam = int(input())
    if spam == 1:
        print ('Hello')
        continue
    elif spam == 2:
        print ('Howdy')
        continue
    elif spam != 0:
        print ('Greeting')
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
print ('Enter value of spam')
spam = input()
while spam != "" or spam == 0:
  if int(spam) == 1:
    print ('Hello')
  elif int(spam)== 2:
    print ('Howdy')
  elif int(spam)!= 0:
    print ('Greeting')
  print ('Enter value of spam')
  spam = input()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a try-except block to handle any situation where your user's input can't be understood as an integer:

```
while True: 
    print ('Enter value of spam') 
    try:
        spam = int(input())
    except ValueError:
        spam = 0
    if spam == 1: 
        print ('Hello') 
        continue 
    elif spam == 2: 
        print ('Howdy') 
        continue 
    elif spam != 0: 
        print ('Greeting') 
        continue
```

Comment: I think I was too dumb that I haven't realize to use the int conversion inside the if statements. And also the try-except block helps a lot. Thank you very much guys.